# How to split cascades levels in dlib frontal face detector?

Tags: c++, dlib

Follow up: [openface/issue/157](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/issues/157#issuecomment-233597331)

I am trying to split the five level cascade in the dlib frontal face detector to three level (front, front looking but rotated left, and front looking but rotated right one)

[Evgeniy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3209505/evgeniy) suggested to split the detector in C++. I am not familiar with C++. When I look into [frontal_face_detector.h](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h), `get_serialized_frontal_faces` returns a base64 encoded object.

I learned how to save a existing detector into a `.svm` file:

```cpp
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector(); 

    dlib::serialize("new_detector.svm") << detector;  

    std::cout<<"End of the Program"<<endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

So how to split the cascade and save the new detector to a `.svm` file?

Also will the detector performance increase by reducing the pyramid level from <6> to a lower value in [frontal_face_detector.h](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just read [object detector documentation](http://dlib.net/dlib/image_processing/object_detector_abstract.h.html#object_detector) and you will find explanation.
Here is code that will split detector into parts, reconstruct original and limit the pyramid level:

```
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector(); 

    dlib::serialize("current.svm") << detector;

    std::vector<frontal_face_detector> parts;
    // Split into parts and serialize to disk
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < detector.num_detectors(); ++i)
    {
        dlib::frontal_face_detector part(detector.get_scanner(), detector.get_overlap_tester(), detector.get_w(i));
        dlib::serialize("part" + std::to_string(i) + ".svm") << part;
        parts.push_back(part);
    }

    // Reconstruct original detector
    frontal_face_detector reconstructed(parts);
    dlib::serialize("reconstructed.svm") << reconstructed;

    // Create detector that will work only on one level of pyramid
    typedef dlib::scan_fhog_pyramid<dlib::pyramid_down<6> > image_scanner_type;
    image_scanner_type scanner;
    scanner.copy_configuration(detector.get_scanner());
    scanner.set_max_pyramid_levels(1); //try setting to 2, 3...
    frontal_face_detector one_level_detector = dlib::object_detector<image_scanner_type>(scanner, detector.get_overlap_tester(), detector.get_w());

    std::cout<<"End of the Program"<<endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

And NO, changing pyramid level from <6>  to any other value will not help much, because *6* is not the limit of pyramid levels, but its a proportion of the scales in pyramid:

6 = 5/6

5 = 4/5

...

Comment: Thanks. That worked. 
Correct me if I am wrong:
1. According to this [comment](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h#L29), part - 0 is front looking, part - 2 is left looking, part - 3 is right looking and so on.
2. If I want only left looking and right looking, I need to push back part 1 and part 2 to parts vector and reconstruct it.

Comment: Also, What is the  max_pyramid_levels in the default frontal face detector? For me set_max_pyramid_levels(8) worked for [small face](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/images/examples/clapton-2.jpg) and comparatively [large face](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/images/examples/lennon-2.jpg).

Comment: @vijayenthiransubramaniam, As I remember, it's unlimited (1000 or so)